# Modify spring saml sample application with https secured idp url

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, adfs, spring-saml

I am trying to use sample application for inhouse adfs now,  the difference is SSOCircle idp url is not http secured, whereas the adfs url I am configuring is https secured. 
I have explained my approach here 
[Spring saml sample application with https idp url throws exception: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853792/spring-saml-sample-application-with-https-idp-url-throws-exception-no-idp-was-c)

Could you please look into the same and explain me the steps to make https url working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to do is add the ssl certificate to your saml keystore.

You can get this ssl certificate a couple of ways.  One way is to view the idP logon form in your browser, then export the certificate using browser functionality.

Spring also provide a utility program for extracting the ssl certificate.  Check out this link...

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-key-management-ssl-keys

Comment: should it be the same ssl certificate being used in adfs? So I ll have to ask for the ssl certificate on adfs server from IT team, and import that ssl certificate in tomcat on my application? Or can that certificate be fetched from idp metadata?